# AngularJS erro templateUrl não encontra arquivo html

Tags: angularjs

## PROBLEMA

Estou com um problema na minificação do meu projeto quando ele chama o templateUrl na rota, estou utilizando o grunt para gerar minha build. No meu ambiente de desenvolvimento ele funciona corretamento, somente possui esse erro na minha build gerada.

### Pesquisa

Pesquisei para ver se não era nenhum problema de DI mas está tudo correto.

## CÓDIGO

#### app.js

```
angular
      .module('myModule', [
        'ngResource',
        'ngRoute',
        'myModule.agenda',
        'myModule.agenda.controller',
        'myModule.agenda.services',
        'myModule.agenda.filters'
      ])
      .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'app/scripts/agenda/views/welcome.html',
                controller: 'mainCtrl'
            })
      });
```

Pastas

- App

  - scripts

    - agenda

      - views

        - main.html
    - app.html

Comment: Você está utilizando o Uglify para minificar?

Comment: Esse mesmo Lucas

Comment: Por acaso a sua aplicação local roda no root, e no cliente roda em um subdiretorio?

Comment: Roda somente local no momento e sim root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Entendendo o problema

O AngularJS Injeta a dependência dos services de acordo com o nome do argumento quando você não especifica isso.

Neste caso, o argumento `$routeProvider` esta sendo minificado e portanto, impedido de ser injetado. Então provavelmente o erro que está logando é `undefined is not a function`.

### A solução

Você deve chamar o `config` passando não direto a `function`, mas um `array` onde os valores são as dependências e a ultima posição do array é a function que vai usa-lás:

Exemplo:

```
.config(['$dependencia1', '$dependencia2', function($dependencia1,$dependencia2){} ]);
```

Dessa forma, a minificação não causaria problemas, pois ele mantém as `strings` nos estados originais. O arquivo minificado ficaria assim:

```
.config(['$dependencia1','$dependencia2',function(a,b){}]);
```

Onde `a` recebeu a injeção da `$dependencia1` e `b` recebeu a injeção da `$dependencia2`. Caso não tivesse este array, o Angular buscaria services registrados onde seus nomes fossem `a` e `b`

### Copy 'n' Paste

Deve-se apenas dizer explicitamente qual é a injeção de `$routeProvider` expecificando isso no array de dependências que vai para o config:

```
angular
      .module('myModule', [
        'ngResource',
        'ngRoute',
        'myModule.agenda',
        'myModule.agenda.controller',
        'myModule.agenda.services',
        'myModule.agenda.filters'
      ])
      .config(['$routeProvider',function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'app/scripts/agenda/views/welcome.html',
                controller: 'mainCtrl'
            });
      }]);
```

Comment: E ai AnisanWesley, então fiz a alteração mas ocorre o mesmo problema. Quando coloco a dependência dessa forma que você sugestiono em qualquer lugar da erro mas se eu colocar assim **.$inject = ['$scope** ele funciono nas outras dependendicias, mas meu problema de ** not found ** ainda está lá.

Answer (score 2):

No stackoverflow em inglês achei uma pergunta semelhante.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17238759/angular-module-minification-bug

Nela, diz que se deve definir a propriedade `mangle:false`. Para ser mais específico, dessa forma:

```
uglify: {
  options: {
    mangle: false
  },
```

Caso haja alguma dúvida, é só pedir nos comentários que eu complemento a resposta.

Comment: Opa bom dia Lucas, inseri essa opção no meu Gruntfile.js mas ocorre a mesma coisa.

Comment: No link diz que rodar o `ng-min` antes de rodar o `uglify` resolve o problema também.

Comment: Opa, tentei tb e nd... meu Gruntfile.js pra facilitar.[Gruntfile.js](http://pastebin.com/b5GS1sXp)

Answer (score 0):

### DEDUÇÃO DO PROBLEMA

O erro ocorria porque ele não estava levando o arquivo .html junto, o grunt fazia com que a pasta script tratasse apenas de concatenar minificar o arquivos JS e levar o arquivo final e o restando (que seria meu html) não iria na build.

### SOLUÇÃO

Minha solução foi criar uma pasta um diretório antes do scripts (raiz do app) chamada de views, onde sigo a ordem dos módulos criado na pasta script.

Ficando assim: **/app/views/agenda/index.html**

### EXTRA

Tenho certeza que devem ter outras possíveis soluções até mesmo mexendo no arquivo Grantfile.js, se tiverem alguma solução ficarei interessado em ver. Obrigado a todos pela ajuda!

Comment: Acabei de encontrar uma solução parecida, nela diz para fazer `templateUrl: '../app/scripts/agenda/views/welcome.html'` porque quando voce minifica o HTML ele muda de lugar, então links relativos acabam ficando perdidos. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22718455/using-usemin-within-angularjs-partials

Comment: Interessante vou tentar.

Comment: conseguiu algo?

Comment: Não ocorreu o mesmo problema...